# Will using prototype function as event handler cause memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

```
var foo = function () {
}

foo.prototype.bar = function () {
}

var test = function () {
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost");
    socket.onopen = foo.prototype.bar; 
    //Or socket.addEventListener('open', foo.prototype.bar)
}

test();
```

socket should be subject to GC right after test is executed. But it has an onopen handler and it holds a reference to the socket object.

Since the function is defined on the prototype so it will live forever (I think). The question is will that function prevent socket from getting GCed.

I.E. do I need to unsubscribe to the open event after its opened to prevent memory leak?

Comment: If you set a specific instance for `foo.prototype`, you can null it out when you are done with it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus even if I null it out the reference is still on the function defined on the prototype isn't it..

Comment: If you null out the prototype, it won't exist for a function to be attached to it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus im using typescript class and ts loves prototype. Im just wondering if I need to clear out all the event handlers defined in class or am I safe from mem leak. (and im curious about the answer. Want to know if theres some magic the browser can do to avoid this)

Comment: This should easily be testable, but i do not believe this to be an issue - the reference is from the to be collected object to the prototype, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the function is defined on the prototype so it will live forever (I think).

Yes.

> The question is will that function prevent socket from getting GCed?

No. The socket object is referencing the function, not the other way round.

> socket should be subject to GC right after test is executed.

Yes, the `socket` variable is, but the socket object you created (which contains the reference to the handler) is still alive - it is referenced by the internal listener that receives payload from the network.

> Do I need to unsubscribe to the open event after its opened to prevent memory leak?

No. You only need to unsubscribe when you want to keep the socket open but stop listening.

You will however need to close the socket when you are done with your test!